# help please , I keep getting the error of "File ended while scanning use of \frac

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}

  \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
        \chead{Report Project 1}
        \rhead{MS455/MS555}
    \rfoot{\today}


\title{Project 1}
\author{Effat Ashi 1621505}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{enumerate}
\item{\textbf{The cumulative distribution function}}    \\
\item{\textbf[Matlab figures]}\\
\item{\textbf{Mean and variance}}\\
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mu=E[x]=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-{\lambda}{x}}\\
=\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-{\lambda}{x}}dx\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}\\
Then we integrate by parts\\
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
=\lambda\left[-xe^{-{\lambda}{x}}\right]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-{\lambda}{x}} dx\\
=\lambda\left[0+\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}{\lambda}\right]_0^\infty\\
=\lambda\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\\
=\frac{1}{\lambda}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}\\
Now we can calculate the varience from the mean\\
\begin{equation*}
\sigma^2=$$\mathbb{E}$[(x-\mu)^2]=$$\mathbb{E}$[x^2]-$$\mathbb{E}$[x^2]\\
$\mathbb{E}$[x^2]=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2\lambda e^{-{\lambda}{x}} dx\\
=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\\
\sigma^2=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\\
\sigma=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\mu
\end{equation*}
\item{\textbf{Confidence interval}\\
\textbf{Theta=2}\\
\textbf{Matlab Codes}\\
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item{Histograms}\\
    \item{Confidence interval}\\
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For one, this term `\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}{\lambda}` is missing a right brace.  For another, the use of `$` and `$$` inside an equation environment, is not appropriate syntax. (multiple times  in one equation this happens).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please try yourself to generate a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) i.e. the smallest piece of code which generates *the same* error.  There's a lot of code here and going through it all is a lot of effort, you should try yourself to comment out parts of the code and see if the error changes/goes away to try and work out which part or even which line is causing you the problem.

Comment: I will ask again by smaller piece with the same error

Comment: @Effat please just edit this question and replace the current code with the smaller piece.  Also have you seen Steven's comment?  This should resolve at least one.

Comment: I tried to do so , is it worked ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I removed $ the error still appear!!

Comment: Braces in `\item{\textbf{Confidence interval}\\ ` are not balanced; missing right brace in `\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}{\lambda}`; remove all `$` signs from 3rd equation.

Comment: Likely unrelated, but note that it should be `\item text`, not `\item{text}\\ `. The braces are unnecessary, and the `\\ ` is wrong.

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles, though you may want to revise its format.

EDITED to reflect and remove what others have noted:

1. your wrong usage of the `\item` syntax (i.e., what follows `\item` should not be embraced)
2. the use of `\\`  within normal text is discouraged and generally totally unnecessary.
3. Additional alignment tabs `&` were added to your equations to take advantage of new alignment possibilities.

In addition to adding `aligned` to the 3rd equation set, I did as I noted in my final comment to your question:

1. Right brace in `\item{\textbf{Confidence interval}\\` is missing;
2. missing right brace in `\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}{\lambda}`;
3. remove all `$` signs from 3rd equation.

Here is the revised MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}

  \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
        \chead{Report Project 1}
        \rhead{MS455/MS555}
    \rfoot{\today}


\title{Project 1}
\author{Effat Ashi 1621505}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{The cumulative distribution function}
\item \textbf[Matlab figures]
\item \textbf{Mean and variance}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mu=E[x]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-{\lambda}{x}}\\
&=\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-{\lambda}{x}}dx\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Then we integrate by parts
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&=\lambda\left[-xe^{-{\lambda}{x}}\right]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-{\lambda}{x}} dx\\
&=\lambda\left[0+\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}\right]_0^\infty\\
&=\lambda\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now we can calculate the varience from the mean
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sigma^2&=\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)^2]=\mathbb{E}[x^2]-\mathbb{E}[x^2]\\
\mathbb{E}[x^2]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2\lambda e^{-{\lambda}{x}} dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\\
\sigma^2&=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\\
\sigma&=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\mu
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\item \textbf{Confidence interval}

\textbf{Theta=2}

\textbf{Matlab Codes}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Histograms
    \item Confidence interval
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll add my version for the (somewhat different) code in the other (closed) post from the O.P. It requires `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} %
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor, fancyhdr} %
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} \newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon } \newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}

\pagestyle{fancy} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} \chead{Report Project 1} \rhead{MS455/MS555} \rfoot{\today}

\title{Project 1} \author{Effat Ashi 1621505}

\begin{document}

\maketitle%

\[ f(x) = \begin{dcases} \frac{1}{\theta } e^{- \tfrac{x}{\theta }} & \text{for  } x \geq 0 \\[0.5ex]
  0 & \text{for } x < 0
  \end{dcases} , \]
  where $\theta$ is a positive parameter, that is $\theta > 0$.

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*. , wide] %
    \item{\textbf{The cumulative distribution function}}%
    To produce the CDE we need to integrate%
    \begin{gather*}
      f(t)=\frac{1}{\theta } e^{- \frac{t}{\theta }} \\%
      \intertext{from $ 0 $ to $ x $ as the case is when $ x $ greater than $ 0 $. }%
      F(x)  =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\theta } e^{- \frac{t}{\theta }}\,dt . \\
      \shortintertext{Set  $ \lambda=\frac{1}{\theta } $.  Then}%
      F(x)  =\int_{0}^{x}{\lambda }e^{-{t}\lambda }\,dt=1-e^{-{x}{\lambda }}=1-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta }}. \\
      \shortintertext{We have} %
      F(x)\in[0,1] \quad \forall x\ge0
    \end{gather*}%

    \ \item{\textbf{The inverse function}}\ From question 1, %
    \begin{gather*}%
      F(x)=1-e^{-{x}{\lambda }},\quad\ F(x)\in[0,1]\quad \forall x \ge 0 \\%
      \intertext{Firstly, we write it as an equation}
      y=1-e^{-x\lambda } \iff 1-y=e^{-x\lambda } \iff 1-F(x)=e^{-x\lambda }\\ %
      \intertext{By taking the ln from both sides we get}%
      -\lambda x=\ln(1-F(x)),\enspace \text{whence}\quad x=\smash[t]{\frac{\ln(1-F(x))}{-\lambda }}.  \\[1ex]%
        F(x) \in [0,1]\ 0\leq F(x)\geq 1   \Rightarrow  1-F(x)=U  \in [0,1]. \\ %
        \intertext{$ U $ \ is a uniform  random  variable and}
        x=\frac{-1}{\lambda } \ln(U) %
      \end{gather*} %

      \item{\textbf{Matlab figures}}\ %

      \ \item{\textbf{Mean and variance}}%
      \begin{align*}
        \mu      & =E[x] =\int_{0}^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-{\lambda }{x}}\ =\lambda \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-{\lambda }{x}}dx          \\ %
                 & =\lambda \left[-xe^{-{\lambda }{x}}\right]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{\lambda }\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-{\lambda }{x}} dx \\ %
                 & =\lambda \left[0+\frac{1}{\lambda }\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda }\right]_0^\infty%
        =\lambda \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\ =\frac{1}{\lambda }
        \intertext{Now we can calculate the variance from the mean: }%
        \sigma^2 & =\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu )^2] =\mathbb{E}[x^2]-(\mathbb{E}[x])^2%
        =\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2\lambda e^{-{\lambda }{x}} dx \\ %
                 & =\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\ \sigma^2=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}%
        =\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\ \sigma=\frac{1}{\lambda }=\mu %
      \end{align*} %

      \item{\textbf{Confidence interval}}%
    \end{enumerate} %

\end{document}
```

[image]